# Show sound input settings by default in macOS Control Center

Tags: audio, settings, plist, defaults, control-center

On macOS, it's possible to modify sound settings from within control center (icon in menubar).

By default, when clicking on sound settings in Control Center, only the audio output is configurable. An `option` click on the sound settings in Control Center displays the audio input settings as well.

[image: Control Center Audio Input Selection]

Is there a way to show audio input settings by default without option clicking? Perhaps there's a `plist` setting that controls this.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?